# Displaying "ZipArchive Object" Message in php Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I am working on a project in which i need to import data from excelsheet to database.

When i execute a excelsheet it works fine and the data from the excelsheet
is sucessfully imported into the table of database, but a message is dispalyed at the time of code execution.

The code is running fine but at runtime a message displayed ::

```
ZipArchive Object ( [status] => 0 [statusSys] => 0 [numFiles] => 11 [filename] => C:\xampp\htdocs\bitcoinreports\uploads\data123.xlsx [comment] => )
```

Here is the code of the controller::

```
public function execute_excel(){

    if(!empty($_POST)){

    $file_name = $_FILES['report_file']['name'];

    $this->load->library('excel');

    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

   //According to me the problem is occur because of below given 4 lines of code

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');

    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bitcoinreports/uploads/'.$file_name;

    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

    $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  

    for($i=2; $i<=$arrayCount; $i++){

    $name = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$i)->getValue();

    $email = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getValue();

    $phone = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$i)->getValue();

    $details = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$i)->getValue();   

    $location = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$i)->getValue();

    $data_user = array(

    "name" => $name,"email" => $email ,"phone" => $phone ,"details" => $details ,"location" => $location);

    $checkValue=$this->dashboard_model->check_data($name,$email,$phone,$details,$location);

    if($checkValue>0)
    {
    //echo "Some Statement";
    }
    else{
    $this->dashboard_model->add_data($data_user);
    }
    }

  }

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success',"Records Inserted SucessFully !!!");

        $data['content'] = "admin/upload/execute_report";

        $data['title'] = "Execute Reports";

        $data['current_open'] = 'execute_excel';

        $data['current_page'] = 'result_add';

        $this->load->view('admin/dashboard/common', $data);


 }
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: At which location in your code this error is produced? And why is it an error?

Comment: @hotzst    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);   
at this line of code i get error